# Reloading a paginated mat-table fails to display rows in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material, datasource

I have a mat-table that loads data from firebase.

all-matches.component.html

```
...
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    ...
    <ng-container matColumnDef="rank">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Rank </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let entry"> {{entry.rank}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weightClass">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight Class </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let entry"> {{entry.weightClass}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    ...
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
...
```

Per recommendations online (that I don't fully understand yet), I opted to use a dataSource object to populate my table. The dataSource gets instantiated in all-matches.component.ts:

all-matches.component.ts

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-matches',
  templateUrl: './all-matches.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-matches.component.scss']
})
export class AllMatchesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  private columnsToDisplay = ['rank','weightClass', 'ageClass','athlete1Name', 'athlete2Name', 'gender','tournamentName','location', 'date', 'matchRating', 'videoUrl']; //TODO make this dynamic somehow
  private loading = true;
...
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private authService: AuthorizationService, private d3Service: D3Service, private dbService: DatabaseService, private textTransformationService: TextTransformationService, private dataSource: MatchDataSource) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.pageSize = 2; //TODO increase me to something reasonable
    this.dataSource = new MatchDataSource(this.dbService);
    this.dataSource.loadMatches('test', '', '', 0, this.pageSize);
    this.dbService.getMatchCount().subscribe(results=>{
      this.matchCount = results;
    });
    ...
    }
```

MatchDataSource.model.ts

```
import {CollectionViewer, DataSource} from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import { BehaviorSubject ,  Observable , of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Match } from './match.model';
import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MatchDataSource implements DataSource<Match> {

  private matchesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Match[]>([]);
  private loadingMatches = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public loading$ = this.loadingMatches.asObservable();

  constructor(private dbService: DatabaseService) {}

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Match[]> {
    return this.matchesSubject.asObservable();
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    this.matchesSubject.complete();
    this.loadingMatches.complete();
  }

  loadMatches(matchId: string, filter = '',
  sortDirection='asc', pageIndex: number, pageSize: number) {
    this.loadingMatches.next(true);
    this.dbService.getKeyOfMatchToStartWith(pageIndex, pageSize).subscribe(keyIndex=>{
      this.dbService.getMatchesFilteredPaginator(keyIndex, pageSize).pipe(
        catchError(()=> of([])),
        finalize(()=>{
          //TODO the tutorial here https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/ toggled the loading spinner off here, but it seemed to work better below for me?
        })
      )
      .subscribe(matches => {
        let results = this.makeIntoArray(matches);
        this.matchesSubject.next(results);
        // console.log("loading done");
        this.loadingMatches.next(false);
      });
    });
  }

  makeIntoArray(matches: any){
    let results = []; //TODO there should be a way to tighten the below up
    for(var i in matches){
      let obj1 = {id:matches[i].id};
      if(matches[i].matchDeets){
        let obj2 = matches[i].matchDeets;
        obj1 = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
      }
      results.push(obj1);
    }
    // console.log(results);
    return results;
  }
}
```

The rows load just fine (although I have some concern with scaling, since I'm counting total rows with an observable (why is there no straightforward way to count entries in a firebase node??)).

However, when I reload the page, the spinner is never dismissed and the rows never populate. I welcome any advice!

Reproducing my issue:

```
git clone https://github.com/Atticus29/dataJitsu.git
cd dataJitsu
git checkout matTableSO
```

Make an api-keys.ts file in /src/app and populate it with the text to follow

api-keys.ts

```
export var masterFirebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCaYbzcG2lcWg9InMZdb10pL_3d1LBqE1A",
    authDomain: "dataJitsu.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://datajitsu.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "495992924984"
  };

export var masterStripeConfig = {
  publicApiTestKey: "pk_test_NKyjLSwnMosdX0mIgQaRRHbS",
  secretApiTestKey: "sk_test_6YWZDNhzfMq3UWZwdvcaOwSa",
  publicApiKey: "",
  secretApiKey: ""
};
```

Then, back in your terminal session, type:

```
npm install
ng serve
```

Comment: Can you provide a version with just TableComponent on StackBlitz? Instead of creating an account can you provide a test username/password for login.
I also noticed you are loading 6 scripts in `all-matches.component.html`. May I know the reasoning behind this as well.

Comment: I won't be able to provide a StackBlitz version on the timeline of the bounty, unfortunately (there are a lot of moving parts just to get the mat-table and its associated classes set up). As for the scripts, they are a vestige of something I was doing in the past and should no longer be necessary for the current problem.

Comment: As for username/password, use ronufi@emojamu.sz for username and "ValidPassword23" for the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating BehaviorSubject object & then converting it to Observable is good way but the changes are occurring in different context than the AllMatchesComponent. So, not only you've to subscribe to changes in $loading in component class but also updating model value (change detection)
You can do that in below ways:

**1**. Using `NgZone.run()` : `NgZone` is an injectable service for executing work inside or outside of the Angular zone. Running functions via run will allow you to reenter Angular zone from a task that was executed out of context.
So, inject NgZone in both component & MatchDataSource:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
constructor(..., private nz: NgZone) { }
```

Then, in AllMatchesComponent update datasource object creation:

```
this.dataSource = new MatchDataSource(this.dbService, this.nz);
```

And for this update service code as:

```
  loadMatches(matchId: string, filter = '',
  sortDirection='asc', pageIndex: number, pageSize: number) {
    this.loadingMatches.next(true);
    this.dbService.getKeyOfMatchToStartWith(pageIndex, pageSize).subscribe(keyIndex=>{
      this.dbService.getMatchesFilteredPaginator(keyIndex, pageSize).pipe(
        catchError(()=> of([])),
        finalize(()=>{
          //TODO 
        })
      )
      .subscribe(matches => {
        let results = this.makeIntoArray(matches);
        this.nz.run(() => {
          this.matchesSubject.next(results);
          this.loadingMatches.next(false);
        });

      });
    });
  }
```

Here only thing I've updated in your code is, in subscribe I've enclosed .next() call with NgZone.run(). No other change required & async pipe should work as expected

You can refer [**Github Repo example**](https://github.com/shant24k/dataJitsu). Check for `AllMatchesComponent` & `MatchDataSource`

**2**. In another approach you can just skip the use of `async` pipe & just subscribe to `datasource.$loading` and then update the change in model var using `ChangeDetectorRef`.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(..., private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef ) {  }

ngOnInit() {

//Keep other code as it is
// Uncomment loading$ subscribe & update it as below

  this.dataSource.loading$.subscribe(result =>{
     this.showLoader = result;
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

Make no changes in MatchDataSource service. Update loader template code to:

```
<div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="showLoader">
        <mat-spinner id="spinner"></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

This will then work as expected & changes will updated.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Shantanu! I'm curious: how did you learn this?

Comment: @Atticus29 Welcome. It's how angular works, unlike angularjs here change detection cycle runs only once (by NgZone). So, as you're updating value to observable correctly in service, problem was obviously in updating the value across whole app. So, these are ways in which it can be done manually (& it's actually good performance wise). There's even 3rd way which I've missed mentioning: `ApplicationRef` api with `tick` method. It'll also serve same purpose.